# Is it possible to query a table with more coupled values with same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There is month-year couple values in query side. But table has separated columns for year and month. If there is only one month-year pair (for example 7-2013) no problem with,

```
SELECT pik.pk_yil AS pkYil, 
       pik.pk_ay As pkAy, 
       krm.kurum_adi AS krmAdi, 
       ilc.ilac_adi AS ilcAdi, 
       pik.ilac_parti_no AS ilcPN, 
       pik.ilac_skt AS ilcSKT
FROM piyasa_kontrol pik
     LEFT JOIN kurum_adlari krm ON pik.pk_il=krm.id 
     LEFT JOIN ilaclar ilc ON pik.ilac_id=ilc.id 
WHERE pk_il=
    (
      SELECT evrak_gonderen 
      FROM evraklar 
      WHERE id=124 OR gelen_evrak_etakip=124
    )
    AND pik.pk_yil = 2012 
    AND pk_ay = 6
```

How should i set query if there is more then one pair like "7-2013, 8-2013, 3-2011"? Also month and years has bonded for querying logic.
Language is php and db is mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for `or`?

```
WHERE pk_il = (SELECT evrak_gonderen 
               FROM evraklar 
               WHERE id=124 OR gelen_evrak_etakip=124
              ) AND
     ((pik.pk_yil=2012 AND pk_ay=6) OR
      (pik.pk_yil=2013 AND pk_ay=7) OR
      (pik.pk_yil=2013 AND pk_ay=8) OR
      (pik.pk_yil=2011 AND pk_ay=3)
     )
```

Comment: It seems simple for experienced one but i am newbie. Thank you @Gordon Linoff.